# Multiply Values in Sum in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use the following equation in Excel, but it's giving me value errors

`=SUM(I5:I34+I61+((I35:I60)*2))`

When I evaluate it, it keeps telling me that `I5:I34` and `I35:I60` are `#VALUE`. Every value in this range is just numbers so I don't see why it shouldn't work?

I've tried re-writing it multiple ways, and even when Excel suggested a formula this is what it gave me, but it's still giving me errors. Some of the cells do have a value of `0`, but I wouldn't think that would cause any problems?

Comment: how about `=SUM(I5:I34,I61)+(SUM(I35:I60))*2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `=SUM` you cannot used `+`.

If like to use `+` then do following `=A1+A2*A3`

For your question you can use following formula.

`=SUM(I5:I34,I61)+(SUM(I35:I60)*2)`